# Encoding Provider for HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming

Is there any encoding provider that support HTTP Live streaming with floating point EXTINF
or timed metadata? I experimented with both using Apple's mediafilesegmenter tool. Any of the two helps scrubbing to be perfectly accurate on iOS 4.3+

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My gstreamill is a live encoder with HTTP Live Streaming output.

1. go to http://github.com/i4tv/gstreamill, clone the source.
2. Follow the README in the source install and run gstreamill.
3. Use B/S user interface create HTTP Live streaming.

Comment: You should disclose that you are that project's maintainer (in this and in your other answers). Also, you should provide an example as to how your project can solve the OP's issue.